# grafana can’t login after upgrading to v7.0

Tags: grafana

After upgrading to v7.0 we are unable to login to grafana. At the login screen, after typing in a the username and password, a green banner will pop up which states “Logged In”, but the webpage will refresh and be stuck at the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another browser. Google and Firefox works for me while Microsoft edge does not.